# How to pass a .json file from AWS eventbridge to AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am currently working on a project that is using event-based architecture. I created a lambda function that takes parameters from lambda event and processes it according to logic. We are using a eventbridge to trigger the lambda function daily on a fixed schedule. I wanted to pass this .json file from s3 to eventbridge and that eventbridge should send it to AWS lambda. Any solutions? (I wanted to pass params dynamically by reading .json file)

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71553179/13126651

Comment: @jatinMehrotra, I think in this question, they are passing static values to lambda. In my case, I wanted to use values dynamically by fetching the data inside .json file and use it in the eventbridge to pass it to lambda

Comment: Then you may need to use lambda to read from s3 and then pass those json value to other lambda using step functions and scheduling expression ( cron ) inside step functions https://medium.com/@tturnbull/passing-data-between-lambdas-with-aws-step-functions-6f8d45f717c3, https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc